# Is it normal distributed?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, standard-error

My Error's plot from a linear regression

[image].

Is it Normal distributted? If not, why? What that negative big bar means?

The code used is:

```
  library(MASS)
sresid <- studres(reg3) 
hist(sresid, freq=FALSE, 
     main="Distribution of Studentized Residuals")
xfit<-seq(min(sresid),max(sresid),length=40) 
yfit<-dnorm(xfit) 
lines(xfit, yfit)
```

Edited:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A histogram is not the best graph to do this. You are better of using a Q-Q plot, e.g. [Regression - How do I know if my residuals are normally distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96042/).

If you do that, I suspect you will see that an important deviation from normality/Gaussianity is that the residuals are right-skewed.

Comment: Ill add the qq-plot

Comment: The QQ plot shows that @Maarten 's suspicions are confirmed. There is a long right tail.