# How to calculate normal score in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, quantiles, qq-plot

I use the qqnorm function to calculate normal scores in R:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- qqnorm(x)$x
```

How are these kind of normal scores calculated?

Comment: You would be better on an R-specific site. You could also try reading the documentation for qqnorm right to the end which gives you a clue.

Comment: As well as the indicated duplicate, additional details are discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96042/regression-how-do-i-know-if-my-residuals-are-normally-distributed).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the exact calculation used by functions in R by combing a number of calls. You can follow some easy steps to "get at" most. This is outlined below, with skipped code lines (for brevity) indicated with `...` on their own lines.

First, try to call up the function without parentheses, as such: `qqnorm`. This yields the following:

```
> qqnorm
function (y, ...) 
UseMethod("qqnorm")
<bytecode: 0x00000000094f9250>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

This tells us that `qqnorm` uses a method. To look at what methods are available, we can use `methods()`.

```
> methods(qqnorm)
[1] qqnorm.default*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Having identified the method, we can then use `getAnywhere()` to examine the source code.

```
> getAnywhere(qqnorm.default)
A single object matching ‘qqnorm.default’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for qqnorm from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (y, ylim, main = "Normal Q-Q Plot", xlab = "Theoretical Quantiles", 
    ylab = "Sample Quantiles", plot.it = TRUE, datax = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
    if (has.na <- any(ina <- is.na(y))) {
        yN <- y
...
```